# Magento 2. Do I need custom code(e.g. Plugins) to trigger reindex logic for an Update on Save(realtime) configured Index?

Tags: magento2, indexing

My question is simple and straight forward. 
Do I need to add custom logic to call my indexer(e.g. plugin on afterSave) when the indexer is configured as Update On Save or is Magento supposed to call it for me?

EDIT:

I'm adding a link to an issue that might suggest that UpdateOnSave does not work out of the box for custom indexers https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8866

Also if we take a look at \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product::addCommitCallback Magento uses a plugin to add the reindexRow logic.